# Mocked Async storage test with jest fails, received null, what is correct way to test it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, jestjs, asyncstorage

Hello all I am new in testing, I am just trying to test async storage value, it's set to 25

[image: async value]

This is test I have written as below;

```
test('can read asyncstorage', async () => {
  let val = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isFirst');
  expect(val).toBe('25');
});
```

The error I am getting is like below;

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "25"
    Received: null
```

Did I just misunderstood the concept of writing tests? should I set 25 with mocked setItem function just before calling getItem? If I do that (as below), it passes the test, would it be a right approach?

```
test('can read asyncstorage', async () => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('isSecond', '25');
  let val = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isSecond');
  expect(val).toBe('25');
});
```

Or Is it right way to try to get real stored value and validate it?

Comment: In this case your tests seem to be not running in the current app installation. This is usually the case. Your last piece of code makes sense. This is actually a good thing, when you run this in another computer, you do not want to be manually ensuring the value of isFirst in the emulator there.

Comment: If you are writing a test for AsyncStorage.setItem method, then the last test makes sense because you're setting the value and then confirming if it got set. But why are you writing a test for an existing RN function? You can assume that those methods are working fine. As a practice, always write test cases for the code you wrote while presuming third-party written code to be working as expected.